# Why I get 403 POST request error at Django?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, csrf

Why I get 403 POST request error?

I do not understand what is wrong here ...

```
$('#id_submit').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = new FormData($('form')[0])
  form.append("image", $("input#id_image")[0].files[0])

  var data = {
    form: form,
    image_form: 123
  }

  $.ajax({
    headers: '{{ csrf_token }}',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
  })
})
```

Comment: A header should be a key and value. Try: 'X-CSRFToken: {{ csrf_token }}'.

Comment: The 403 response maybe also have a body. Inspect that for the actual error message. Use DEBUG=True in settings ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not properly set the `{{ csrf_token }}`, you need to inject this in the POST data, or as `X-CSRFToken` header, but not as the *entire* `headers`. See for example the [Django documentation on *Setting the token on the AJAX request*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request).

## In the POST *data*

```
var data = {
    form: form,
    image_form: 123,
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
}
```

## In the POST *header*

Or we can include this in the post headers, like:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}' },
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
});
```

Comment: Tell me how to get the data in the request.POST? It's empty there (request.POST.viewkeys())...

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук: you need to extract the data from the form fields, not just submit the `form`. So you will need to fetch the values, and compose a dictionary with those values.

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук: why do you set `processData` on `false`?

Comment: I get `Illegal invocation`, if `processData` not `false`

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук: yes, that is because, as said before, you will need to fetch the values in the *input* elements, and construct a dictionary. You can not "ship" a form to the server, you can only ship values to the server.

Comment: So you propose to extract each field and write it to the dictionary? And there is no more humane way?)

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук: there is, you can use `form.serialize()` to do that for you, then you only will need to add the extra fileds (`image_form` and `csrftoken`).

Comment: I tried to do it initially. But the problem is that there are images in the form. For some reason they did not get into the serialize...

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук: did you set the `enctype: 'multipart/form-data',`? It also does not look right to use `form.append("image", $("input#id_image")[0].files[0])` here, since here you append a file to your form?

Comment: Or do need to add images with a separate key?